# named[862]: resolver priming query complete: every 20 seconds

Tags: bind

BIND 9.11.3 Ubuntu 18.04  kernel 4.15.0-23

I am running bind9 as my LAN DNS and it is working for all hosts and forwarding to internet through the google DNS IPs

Why does my log have many instances of this message. 3-4 entries per minute :

```
 named[862]: resolver priming query complete
```

I have run

```
 named-checkconf
 named-checkzone
```

without errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known (and fixed in later versions) bug in bind9: https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/issues/752

Note that bind9 9.11 continues to be supported as the long-term support branch, the fix is in 9.13 and later.

A workaround appears to be to run `dig +trace` on any domain frequently enough (every 8–12 hours) that the cache doesn't expire.

Comment: I ran `dig +trace google.com`, but I still get those log lines. Do you have perchance another workaround ? (I'm unable to update to Ubuntu 20.04 and the 18.04 version doesn't seem to go past Bind 9.11.3)

Answer (score 0):

Nice to know; after seeing this I "fixed" it by upgrading to 9.16 in debian `buster-backports`, which fixes those error messages, but adds more dnssec ones, which have a different "fix" (and further changed `/etc/init.d/bind9` to `/etc/init.d/named`).